# Is HTML text input accepting HTML code really bad, or just bad?

Tags: html

Recently I was asked to test our company's internal website(only computers connected to our network have access). I realized that text field inputs run html code that is entered. My boss says that this is not a big deal. We log every change, so in the unlikely event that an employee does something, we would know. I'm not a web developer, so my question is, is there something malicious due to this flaw that could silently effect our organization? Or is my boss correct, anything truly malicious would be very visible and dealt with fairly quickly. Our organization is religiously affiliated and handles a large amount of money, hence the concern.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about computer security, not programming.

Comment: Perhaps it is a better question for http://security.stackexchange.com/ But as a general rule of thumb I would not allow any script to be executed from a user input without setting up an isolate sandbox for the script to run in. Unless you 100% always trust the user environment.

Comment: I don't agree that it's not programming. It definitely is something that programmers *should* be very aware of. Permitting code-insertion within your forms is bad programming behavior and is a discussion that programmers *should* be having.

Edit: And I agree partially with joverall22... It should be avoided... though I wouldn't even use it in an environment that I "100% always trust the user." Users have a way of doing things "accidentally."

Comment: @akuta then it's opinion and opinion will get closed, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be a problem. If it runs HTML code then any attacker can input their own script (using the script tag) and run their own programs (how bad, depends on what is done). If the code they input is saved to the website and ran whenever someone goes to that section of the website then that is a big(er) deal. They can inject their malicious code and effect everyone. It is known as XSS(cross site scripting). If everything is logged then it will probably catch them, but how long until it is noticed, and how many people effected can be a problem. More information in the link below.

link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: Okay, I hadn't been thinking about running scripts. That is definitely very dangerous and while I like to think that our employees are fairly trustworthy, anyone who knows about this could do quite a bit of damage. Thanks for the heads up, I will talk with my boss about fixing the issue.